CSS nth-child selector works everywhere except on X
I just found something very weird. Its about this css selector
div:nth-child(3) a

On X I have a container div selected in my DevTools

Now, with the css selector div:nth-child(3) a I want to find the link holding the 4h text
I copied the HTML from X to produce a demo here. You can see there that it works as expected, I see the correct href value!
Although this sounds super easy, which it is. Simplified the HTML looks like this:
    <div>
        <div><a href="/elonmusk">@elonmusk<a/></div>
        <div>·</div>
        <div>
           <a href="/status/234324234234234">3h</div>
        </div>
    </div>

However, when I try to reproduce this on X.com it doesn't work
To reproduce, first select the container element

Now if I perform that query I get

It selects the first div. It can be fix when I query it as follows
$0.querySelector('div:nth-child(3)').querySelector('a')

Why does it work in my demo and not on X?

Thats why I also tested in my demo with the list (ol). One way or the other, something is going on here which I don't understand

Sorry, I noticed that my demo link didn't work, its fixed now!!

So what do you suggest so I can improve this question?

I can see the same thing, interestingly if you use .querySelectorAll(), you get both the links.

Yep. I do remember that when you use nth-child(x) followed by something else it is ignored or something like that. But that theory is not really supported by my demo

The HTML subtree you looked at is
<div> $0
  <div>
    <a> $1
      <div>
        <span>...</span>
      </div>
    </a>
  </div>
  <div>
    <span>·</span>
  </div>
  <div> $2
    <a> $3
      <time>...</time>
    </a>
  </div>
</div>

Now
$0.querySelectorAll("div:nth-child(3) a") selects all a elements that

are descendants of $0 and
have an ancestor div that is the third among its siblings. This ancestor can be outside of the subtree you are looking at!

The result of this query contains both $3 (with $2 as the ancestor) and $1 (with an ancestor outside of this subtree).
And $0.querySelector("div:nth-child(3) a") returns only the first of these, that is, $1.
What you want is correctly expressed as $0.querySelector("div:nth-child(3)").querySelector("a").

So, if I understand correctly, event though I do $0.querySelector the `div:nth-child(3) can be a parent of $0? Well thats weird but it explains what I'm seeing. Thanks a lot!

That's because your selector doesn't ask for the <a> to be a direct descendant and on X, your <a> element is a descendant of another ancestor <div> that's also the third child of its parent.
The same situation can be reproduced with the following tree:


const parent = document.querySelector(".parent");
const target = parent.querySelector("div:nth-child(3) a");

console.log(target);
div:nth-child(3) { color: red }
div:not(:nth-child(3)) { color: black }
<section>
  <div>a</div>
  <div>b</div>
  <div class="grand-parent"><!-- this also matches div::nth-child(3) -->
    c
    <div>c1</div>
    <div>c2</div>
    <div class="parent">c3
      <div>c3a <a>another a</a></div>
      <div>c3b</div>
      <div>c3d <a>target</a></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>



You probably wanted "div:nth-child(3) > a", which would match your element in X, but the best might be to use the :scope pseudo-selector which will set the root of the selector to the element on which you called the query from:


const parent = document.querySelector(".parent");
const target = parent.querySelector(":scope div:nth-child(3) a");

console.log(target);
<section>
  <div>a</div>
  <div>b</div>
  <div class="grand-parent"><!-- this also matches div::nth-child(3) -->
    c
    <div>c1</div>
    <div>c2</div>
    <div class="parent">c3
      <div>c3a <a>another a</a></div>
      <div>c3b</div>
      <div>c3d <a>target</a></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>




Yes, I should've used that >, I realise (and understand) that now

But even that does not guarantee that the third div is a child of $0, it might also be equal to $0.

@HeikoTheißen you're right, > could also fail. I edited with the :scope selector which seems closer to what OP was after.

Didn't know about the :scope selector so far.
